# What is the mean of a normal random variable transformed via $g(x) = \frac{1}{a+x}$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, density-function

Consider normal random variable $\lambda \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ ($\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$) whose PDF is:

$$
f_\lambda(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{\pi}} \exp \left[ {-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\lambda - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^2} \right]
$$

Transformation $g(x) = \frac{1}{a+x}$ is applied and a new random variable $\Lambda$ is generated as:

$$
\Lambda = g(\lambda) \implies \Lambda = \frac{1}{a + \lambda}
$$

With $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

#### The problem

I want to know **the expected value** of $\Lambda$: $E[\Lambda]$.

My attempt so far was by following the theory. The new PDF is computed according to well known formula:

$$
f_\Lambda(\lambda) = f_\lambda[g^{-1}(\lambda)] \left| \frac{d}{d\lambda}g^{-1}(\lambda) \right|
$$

Which means, after a few calculations:

$$
f_\Lambda(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{\pi}} \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \left( 
\frac{1}{\sigma \lambda} - \frac{a}{\sigma} - \frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right)^2 \right] = \frac{\alpha}{\lambda^2} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \left( 
\frac{1}{\sigma \lambda} - \beta \right)^2 \right]
$$

Having $\alpha = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{\pi}}$ and $\beta = \frac{a}{\sigma} + \frac{\mu}{\sigma}$. Now I can proceed calculating the mean value of $\Lambda$ since I know its PDF by means of: $E[\Lambda] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lambda f_\Lambda(\lambda) d\lambda$:

$$
E[\Lambda] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \left( 
\frac{1}{\sigma \lambda} - \beta \right)^2 \right] d\lambda = \alpha \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \left( 
\frac{1}{\sigma \lambda} - \beta \right)^2 \right] d\lambda
$$

And here is the problem, this integration is kinda tricky:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \left( 
\frac{1}{c_1 x} - c_2 \right)^2 \right] dx
$$

How to solve this?

---

#### Integration attempts

**Attempt 1** I have tried with substitutions, but it is horrible because I might get rid of the negative power of the variable in the exponential, but then I get higher order negative powers of the variable multiplying the exponential :(

**Attempt 2** I know that the exponential integral function is defined as:

$$
\text{Ei}(x) = -\int_{-x}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt
$$

And I have a feeling that the primitive of the integrand might be a function of $\text{Ei}$, but I am not sure.

**Attempt 3** Using complex calculus and the Residue Theorem?

Comment: Since you are interested in computing $\mathbb{E}[g(\lambda)]$ you could have directly done $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a + \lambda} f_{\lambda}(\lambda) d \lambda$. Apart from that I don't the think integral would converge since the expression gets unbounded around $\lambda = -a$.

Comment: The integrand, though not defined in 0 has limit therein!

Comment: $E|\Lambda|=\infty$. The whole thing is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @Kavi: is this possible? This is the PDF of a random variable... can its mean be infinite?

Comment: Of course! The Cauchy distribution has density $\frac 1 {\pi} \frac 1{1+x^{2}}$ and its mean is $\infty$.  @Andry

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, I was not aware that the mean could be infinite, this is kind of a first time here.